# Gaussian filter only darkens image, doesn't blur

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, filtering

I wanted to understand the implementation of the Gaussian filter. In this code I implemented a Gaussian kernel and applied it to image with `filter2D`. But, instead of a blurred image, I only get a darker (for high variance value) and very bright (for low variance value). I tried a fixed `np.ones(3,3)/2` for the kernel, and it successfully blurred the image. What might be the problem?

```
import cv2
import math
import numpy as np

filename = "lenna.png"
winname = "G Team Lets Go"

original = cv2.imread(filename)
cv2.namedWindow(winname)


def gaussian_blurr(image, variance, kernel_size):

    def gaussian(x, y):
        return (1 / (2 * np.pi * variance) * np.exp(-1 * ((math.pow(x, 2) + math.pow(y, 2)) / (2 * variance))))

    kernel = np.zeros((kernel_size, kernel_size))

    for x in range(-int(kernel_size/2), kernel_size-int(kernel_size/2)):
        for y in range(-int(kernel_size/2), kernel_size-int(kernel_size/2)):
            kernel[x+int(kernel_size/2), y+int(kernel_size/2)] = gaussian(x, y)

    padding_size = int(kernel_size/2)
    withBorder = cv2.copyMakeBorder(
        image, padding_size, padding_size, padding_size, padding_size, cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE)

    return cv2.filter2D(image, -1, kernel)


variance = 1
size = 3


def handle_variance(value):
    if value == 0:
        value = 1
    variance = value/100
    cv2.imshow(winname, gaussian_blurr(original, variance, size))


def handle_size(value):
    if value == 0:
        value = 1
    size = value
    cv2.imshow(winname, gaussian_blurr(original, variance, size))


cv2.createTrackbar("Variance", winname, 0, 500, handle_variance)
cv2.createTrackbar("Size", winname, 0, 5, handle_size)

cv2.imshow(winname, gaussian_blurr(original, 0.2, 3))
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: It is likely that your setting for `size` is wrong given your setting for `variance`. You should set `size = 2*ceil(3*sigma)+1`. What you call "variance" is actually the `sigma` parameter, which corresponds to the standard deviation of the distribution. Variance is the square of the standard deviation. I have written on my blog about Gaussian filtering in the past. I recommend you read [this post](https://www.crisluengo.net/archives/22) and also [this one](https://www.crisluengo.net/archives/695).

Comment: @CrisLuengo The 'size' parameter means size of the kernel. I don't understand why I should set size = 2*ceil(3*sigma)+1. And also I have corrected the gaussian   equation.

Comment: I explain in the linked blog posts why the size of the kernel should be set depending on the chosen sigma.